# Create multiple empty .txt files in one folder

Tags: macos, terminal

I need empty .txt files and wanted to know if there is any possibility to do it in the terminal on a mac?

the empty txt files should be named by numbers from 1 to 200, like 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt...200.txt

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run on terminal

```
for i in {1..200}; do echo > ${i}.txt; done
```